# Shift rows in matrix with respect to vector values in Octave/MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

Can I shift rows in matrix `A` with respect to values in vector `v`?

For instance `A` and `v` specified as follows:

```
A =
    1   0   0
    1   0   0
    1   0   0

v =
    0   1   2
```

In this case I want to get this matrix from A:

```
A = 
    1   0   0
    0   1   0
    0   0   1
```

Every `i`-th row in `A` has been shifted by `i`-th value in `v`

Can I do this operation with native functions?
Or should I write it by myself?

I've tried `circshift` function, but I couldn't figure out how to shift rows separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `circshift` does not work as you want and even if you use a vector for the amount of shift, that is interpreted as the amount of shift for each dimension. While it is possible to loop over the rows of your matrix, that will not be very efficient.

More efficient is if you compute the indexing for each row which is actually quite simple:

```
## First, prepare all your input
octave> A = randi (9, 4, 6)
A =

   8   3   2   7   4   5
   4   4   7   3   9   1
   1   6   3   9   2   3
   7   4   1   9   5   5

octave> v = [0 2 0 1];
octave> sz = size (A);


## Compute how much shift per row, the column index (this will not work in Matlab)
octave> c_idx = mod ((0:(sz(2) -1)) .- v(:), sz(2)) +1
c_idx =

   1   2   3   4   5   6
   5   6   1   2   3   4
   1   2   3   4   5   6
   6   1   2   3   4   5

## Convert it to linear index    
octave> idx = sub2ind (sz, repmat ((1:sz(1))(:), 1, sz(2)) , c_idx);

## All you need is to index
octave> A = A(idx)
A =

   8   3   2   7   4   5
   9   1   4   4   7   3
   1   6   3   9   2   3
   5   7   4   1   9   5
```

Comment: I think matlab has just introduced broadcasting in the latest version. :)

Comment: also, it's probably best to `mod` than just add the offset, as it's a fair assumption v might contain negative 'shifts'

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou are you serious about broadcasting in Matlab? Link please. You are right about `mod`, it would support negative values and look sexier. Then it becomes the same as your answer.

Comment: They call it "implicit expansion" instead of "broadcasting", but yes. I saw a pdf from mathworks, can't remember where, but here's a chat on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/matlab/comments/4n7oy9/r2016b_prerelease/

Comment: ah, here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/relnotes_pr.pdf?elqTrackId=41b85927aea240c7b7e638647cca47f3&elq=9c6fe2adcfe5418c8e26e97c22fc02a6&elqaid=13594&elqat=1&elqCampaignId=4303 under new features / mathematics

Comment: function definitions straight in the interpreter too ... that's pretty big, imo. They're basically copying julia :p

Comment: Maybe Julia but Octave has function definition in scripts and command line since as far as I can remember. I don't think they're copying any other language, they're just catching up with all the others. What kind of modern language does not support functions in script files? Only Matlab is that retarded.

Comment: I think "retarded" is too strong a word here. In other aspects Octave is behind Matlab and I never thought of calling it "retarded" :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
% A and v as above. These could be function input arguments
A = [1 0 0; 1 0 0; 1 0 0]; 
v = [0 1 2];                                          
assert (all (size (v) == [1, size(A, 1)]), ...
        'v needs to be a horizontal vector with as many elements as rows of A');

% Calculate shifted indices
[r, c] = size (A);
tmp = mod (repmat (0 : c-1, r, 1) - repmat (v.', 1, c), c) + 1;
Out = A(sub2ind ([r, c], repmat ([1 : r].', 1, c), tmp))  

  Out =

       1     0     0
       0     1     0
       0     0     1
```

If performance is an issue, you can replace `repmat` with an equivalent `bsxfun` call which is more efficient (I use repmat here for simplicity to demonstrate the approach).

Comment: You have your call to `sub2ind` wrong if the number of rows and columns don't match. Try with `A = randi (9, 3, 6)` for example.

Answer (score 1):

With focus on performance, here's one approach using [`bsxfun/broadcasting`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
[m,n] = size(A);
idx0 = mod(bsxfun(@plus,n-v(:),1:n)-1,n);
out = A(bsxfun(@plus,(idx0*m),(1:m)'))
```

Sample run -

```
A =
     1     7     5     7     7
     4     8     5     7     6
     4     2     6     3     2
v =
     3     1     2
out =
     5     7     7     1     7
     6     4     8     5     7
     3     2     4     2     6
```

Equivalent Octave version to use [`automatic broadcasting`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.3/Broadcasting.html) would look something like this -

```
[m,n] = size(A);
idx0 = mod( ((n-v(:)) + (1:n)) -1 ,n);
out = A((idx0*m)+(1:m)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Shift vector with `circshift` in loop, iterating row index.