# Left circular shift in Matlab for each row of a matrix of a different number of positions

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `A` in Matlab of dimension `mxn` composed of zeros and ones, and a matrix `J` of dimension `mx1` reporting some integers from `{1,...,n}`.

I want to construct a matrix `B` of dimension `mxn` such that for

(1) `B(1,:)=A(1,:)`

(2) for `i=2,...,m`, `B(i,:)` is obtained by shifting `A(i,:)` LEFT circular of a number of positions equal to `(J(1)-1)+ (J(2)-1)+...+ (J(i-1)-1)`

This code does what I want

```
m=4;
n=5;
A=[1 0 1 1 0; ...
   0 1 0 0 1; ...
   1 1 0 0 0; ...
   0 0 0 0 1;
J=[2;1;5;8];
B=zeros(m,n);
B(1,:)=A(1,:);

foridx=cumsum(J); %mx1
shift=foridx-(1:1:m).'; %mx1
v=shift(1:m-1); %(m-1)x1

for i=2:m
    B(i,:)=(circshift((A(i,:)).', -v(i-1),1)).';
end
```

I would like to avoid the final loop. I like the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39056658/shift-rows-in-matrix-with-respect-to-vector-values-in-octave-matlab) by Divakar but it is for a right circular shift.

```
Arelevant=A(2:end,:);  
idx0 = mod(bsxfun(@plus,n-v(:),1:n)-1,n);
out = Arelevant(bsxfun(@plus,(idx0*(m-1)),(1:(m-1))'));
B(2:end,:)=out;
```

Could you help me to have something similar for a left circular shift?

Comment: If you use bsxfun you don't really avoid the final loop, bsxfun just hide the loop.

Comment: Ok, I understand, thank you. So, do you think that the performance is exactly the same as my version?

Comment: To measure performance, test the `for` loop and `bsxfun` for the *right* shift case, your code is much clearer as-as anyway... Otherwise, you maybe just need to change the indexing, from `1:n` to `-1:-1:-n` to shift the other direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little trick to perform this operation without loop.

I use an fft in order to shift each line.

```
m=4;
n=5;
A=[1 0 1 1 0; ...
   0 1 0 0 1; ...
   1 1 0 0 0; ...
   0 0 0 0 1;]
J=[2;1;5;8];

foridx=cumsum(J); %mx1
shift=foridx-(1:1:m).'; %mx1
v=[0;shift(1:m-1)]; %(m-1)x1
L=real(round(ifft(fft(A,[],2) .* exp(2i*pi/n*v*(0:m)) ,[],2))) %left shift
R=real(round(ifft(fft(A,[],2) .* exp(-2i*pi/n*v*(0:m)) ,[],2))) %right shift
```

Comment: That's rather clever... I wonder what the performance of this would be for larger sized arrays.

Comment: I honestly don't think that it will be way faster than the loop. Even if the first f of fft mean "fast" =)