# Optimization of column shifting of large matrices (Circshift, etc.)

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, optimization

I am currently looking for the most efficient way to shift and rearrange large matrices. Essentially, I have data with some parabolic shift that needs to be corrected in order to shift the "signal" to a linear event.

I have currently tried the following solutions and tried timing them. Is there any other method that may prove to be more efficient?

```matlab
DATA = ones(100000,501);
DATA(10000,251) = 100;
for i=1:250
    DATA(10000+i^2-1000:10000+i^2+1000,251-i) = 100;
    DATA(10000+i^2-1000:10000+i^2+1000,251+i) = 100;
end
k = abs(-250:1:250).^2;
d = size(DATA,1);
figure(99)
imagesc(DATA)


t_INDEX = timeit(@()fun_INDEX(DATA,k))

t_SNIPPET = timeit(@()fun_SNIPPET(DATA,k))

t_CIRCSHIFT = timeit(@()fun_CIRCSHIFT(DATA,k))

t_INDEX_clean = timeit(@()fun_INDEX_clean(DATA,k))

t_SPARSE = timeit(@()fun_SPARSE(DATA,k))

t_BSXFUN = timeit(@()fun_BSXFUN(DATA,k))


function fun_INDEX(DATA,k)
    DATA_1 = zeros(size(DATA));
    for i=1:size(DATA,2)
       DATA_1(:,i) = DATA([k(i)+1:end 1:k(i)],i);
    end
    figure(1)
    imagesc(DATA_1)
end

function fun_SNIPPET(DATA,k)
    kmax = max(k);
    DATA_2 = zeros(size(DATA,1)-kmax,size(DATA,2));
    for i=1:size(DATA,2)
       DATA_2(:,i) = DATA(k(i)+1:end-kmax+k(i),i);
    end
    figure(2)
    imagesc(DATA_2)
end

function fun_CIRCSHIFT(DATA,k)
    DATA_3 = zeros(size(DATA));
    for i=1:size(DATA,2)
        DATA_3(:,i) = circshift(DATA(:,i),-k(i),1);
    end
    figure(3)
    imagesc(DATA_3)
end

function fun_INDEX_clean(DATA,k)
    [m, n] = size(DATA);
    k = size(DATA,1)-k;
    DATA_4 = zeros(m, n);
    for i = (1 : n)
        DATA_4(:, i) = [DATA((m - k(i) + 1 : m), i); DATA((1 : m - k(i) ), i)];
    end
    figure(4)
    imagesc(DATA_4)
end

function fun_SPARSE(DATA,k)
    [m,n] = size(DATA);
    k = -k;
    S = full(sparse(mod(k,m)+1,1:n,1,m,n));
    DATA_5 = ifft(fft(DATA).*fft(S),'symmetric');
    figure(5)
    imagesc(DATA_5)
end


function fun_BSXFUN(DATA,k)
    DATA = DATA';
    k = -k;
    [m,n] = size(DATA);
    idx0 = mod(bsxfun(@plus,n-k(:),1:n)-1,n);
    DATA_6 = DATA(bsxfun(@plus,(idx0*m),(1:m)'));
    figure(6)
    imagesc(DATA_6)
end
```

Is there any way to decrease computation time for this kind of problem?

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: Please precisely and concisely describe "column shifting", what do you want to achieve? You've provided several different solutions, how is their relative performance? How slow is too slow?

Comment: I've answered [a really similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44968201/left-circular-shift-in-matlab-for-each-row-of-a-matrix-of-a-different-number-of). Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use MATLAB's GPU functions, if your workstation has a GPU. Depending on if the entire data fits on the GPU at once, it will start to outperform CPU circshift at 1000 X 1000 matrix size.

The implementation only requires you to copy your data to the GPU with a single statement, and then operate circshift on the newly created you array.

A small discussion on its performance can be found here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/274619-circshift-slower-on-gpu . Especially, the last post describes a much faster GPU implementation if you actually don't need to circularly shift, but can get away with zero passing on one side, which might be relevant.